# CSS triangle and box inside one DIV

Tags: html, css

is there any way to merge triangle and box created with CSS into the one `<div>`. For now I have got this HTML:

```
<div id="triangle-left"></div>
<div id="box"><!-- Something --></div>
```

And this in CSS:

```
#triangle-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid #602F4F;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    float:left;
}
#box {
    background-color: #602F4F;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", Futura, sans-serif;
}
```

And this is result http://jsfiddle.net/9AyYS/ .

Is there any way to simiplify it into the one `<div>`? Thank you.

Comment: @Jawad It is totaly possible in css3! You could try #box:before pseudo object: http://jsfiddle.net/9AyYS/4/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Comment: right. cool. my bad. +1

Comment: @MartinTurjak Excellent you should probably post this as answer...

Comment: @MartinTurjak add answer for +1

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Ok ... I moved my suggestion from the comment to an answer below =) Thanks a lot guys for the appreciation ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, upon your convincing I moved this here from the comment above =)

The slight modification to Mira's code:

```
#box:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:210px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid #602F4F;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
#box {
    background-color: #602F4F;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0 0 4px 30px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", Futura, sans-serif;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9AyYS/4/)

Comment: "upon your convincing I moved this here from the comment above" right!

Comment: @Jawad hehe ;-) I admit it does not take long to convince me into things ... but to convince me to go for a beer has statistically significantly the shortest convincing times =D